# error installing install chromedriver on linux

Tags: linux, selenium-chromedriver

iam new using linux and i want to install chrome driver using terminal with wget but suddenly i have this error and cant find or open chrome driver. this is my error any solution here?

```
Resolving chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com (chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com)... 34.101.5.80, 2404:f340:4010:1803::2010
```

Connecting to chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com (chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com)|34.101.5.80|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 6206401 (5,9M) [application/zip]
chromedriver_linux64.zip: No such file or directory

Cannot write to ‘chromedriver_linux64.zip’ (Success).

Comment: Please provide the full command you used to try to download the ZIP, including the URL and any other arguments you passed to `wget`.

Comment: You also might not have write permissions for whichever directory you are downloading the file to. If you are downloading the file to your current working directory (which is the default to `wget`), you can check the permissions for your current working directory with `ls -ld .`.

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not questions about using or setting up Linux. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved after manual installation. I'm using Linux.

1. Firstly I downloaded chromedriver from the [chromedriver official download website](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads).
2. After that I moved my chromedriver from `~/Downloads` to `/usr/local/bin` using this line in the terminal:

   ```
   sudo mv ~/Downloads/chromedriver /usr/local/bin
   ```
3. Finally I made the file executable:

   ```
   sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
   ```